Can Neumaier summation be sped up?
Neumaier summation is an improvement of Kahan summation for accurately summing arrays of floats.
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def neumaier_sum(arr):
    s = arr[0]
    c = 0.0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        t = s + arr[i]
        if abs(s) >= abs(arr[i]):
            c += (s - t) + arr[i]
        else:
            c += (arr[i] - t) + s
        s = t
    return s + c

This works well but it is at least four times slower than it would be  were you to add fastmath=True. Unfortunately, fastmath allows rebracketing the sum (associativity) which has the effect of ruining its accuracy so we can't do that.
Here is a test to show the results with different ways of summing. First we make an array of length 1001.
import numpy as np
n = 10 ** 3 + 1
a = np.full(n, 0.01, dtype=np.float64)
a[0] = 10**10
a[-1] = -10**10

We import math so we can use fsum to see the correct answer. We also define a version Neumaier using fastmath.
# Bad version using fastmath
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def neumaier_sum_fm(arr):
    s = arr[0]
    c = 0.0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        t = s + arr[i]
        if abs(s) >= abs(arr[i]):
            c += (s - t) + arr[i]
        else:
            c += (arr[i] - t) + s
        s = t
    return s + c

The results are:
math.fsum       : 9.99
nb_neumaier_sum : 9.99
nb_neumaier_sum_fm: 9.99001693725586

These are the timings:
 %timeit nb_neumaier_sum_fm(a)
350 ns ± 0.983 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
 %timeit nb_neumaier_sum(a)
1.5 µs ± 18.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

Is there any way to speed up this code but have it output exactly what it does now?

The assembly is as follows. The comments were added by chatgpt so please let me know if any of it is wrong.
    movq    8(%rsp), %rcx          # Load the address of the array into rcx
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax         # Load the length of the array into rax
    vmovsd  (%rcx), %xmm1          # Load the first element of the array into xmm1 (s = arr[0])
    leaq    -1(%rax), %rdx         # Calculate (length of array - 1) into rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx             # Test if rdx is zero
    jle .LBB0_1               # If rdx <= 0, jump to .LBB0_1
    movabsq $.LCPI0_0, %rsi       # Load address of constant value (mask for abs)
    movl    $1, %edx               # Initialize loop counter (i = 1)
    vxorpd  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0    # Clear xmm0 (c = 0.0)
    vmovapd %xmm1, %xmm3           # Copy xmm1 (s) to xmm3
    vmovapd (%rsi), %xmm2          # Load abs mask into xmm2

    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_3:
    vmovsd  (%rcx,%rdx,8), %xmm4   # Load arr[i] into xmm4
    vandpd  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm5    # Compute abs(s) into xmm5
    incq    %rdx                   # Increment rdx (i++)
    vaddsd  %xmm4, %xmm3, %xmm1    # Compute t = s + arr[i]
    vandpd  %xmm2, %xmm4, %xmm6    # Compute abs(arr[i]) into xmm6
    vcmpnlesd   %xmm5, %xmm6, %xmm5  # Compare abs(s) and abs(arr[i])
    vsubsd  %xmm1, %xmm3, %xmm6    # Compute (s - t) into xmm6
    vaddsd  %xmm6, %xmm4, %xmm6    # Compute (s - t) + arr[i] into xmm6
    vsubsd  %xmm1, %xmm4, %xmm4    # Compute (arr[i] - t) into xmm4
    vaddsd  %xmm4, %xmm3, %xmm3    # Compute (arr[i] - t) + s into xmm3
    vblendvpd   %xmm5, %xmm3, %xmm6, %xmm3  # Conditional blend based on the comparison
    vaddsd  %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm0    # Update c
    vmovapd %xmm1, %xmm3           # Update s (s = t)
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax             # Compare loop counter with array length
    jne .LBB0_3                # If not equal, loop again

    vaddsd  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0    # Final addition (s + c)
    xorl    %eax, %eax             # Clear eax
    vmovsd  %xmm0, (%rdi)          # Store the result
    retq                        # Return from function


I suspect the short answer is no. That code is as simple as it can be and still work. It might be worth a punt trying to make the expression for c common and only assign the variables in the if statement.  a=s, b = arr[i] (or vice versa) and common code c += (a-t)+b. There is an outside chance that the compiler will see a way to use conditional moves for those assignments which might possibly have lower latency. Worth examining the generated code in a debugger.

Indeed, not in Numba. The loop carried dependency combined with a data-dependent condition break all important optimizations for compilers. There are ways to keep the overall logic and significantly speed-up this function while produce slightly different results (by reordering operations manually and assume FP-math is associative for only few adds). However, such ways require a manual low-level optimization which are not (easily) possibly in Numba (and in fact not so easy even in native languages like C but OK in some other native languages or with C++ libraries).

In fact, this is a well known problem: the higher the accuracy the slower the method (though a good accuracy can be get with a relatively fast code).

I would expect a user named Simd has already considered splitting the array into 4 or more parallel streams and summing each of them independently, then combining the sums at the end. Have you?

Re “The comments were added by chatgpt so please let me know if any of it is wrong”: This is bad and violates Stack Overflow policy. The question could be flagged and deleted by moderators. It is bad because the added comments may be misleading and have to be checked by humans, so that is adding work. And where did the assembly code come from?

@EricPostpischil In its previous post, the OP described that input arrays are of size <1000 and an array of size 1000 here, so multiple threads will introduce a significant overhead (especially regarding the timings). Note that SIMD parallelism is very hard to achieve with Numba if even possible (see comments of the other post about the SLP-vectorizer). ILP could help a bit though miss-prediction may reduce its benefit. Besides, note that it ios possible to get the assembly code of Numba function with the inspect_asm method

@EricPostpischi The assembly is provided by inspect_asm by numba.

Maybe numba wasn't the best choice for you. I used numba in the previous question because it's easy to try. I tried cython on my PC, where numba took 1.25e-5 and cython took 1.00e-5. At first I thought this was due to overhead, but the same difference appeared in larger arrays. I don't know what this means (so I won't post it as an answer). But I think it is worth a try.

@ken is it possible to compare the assembly? I added a cython tag so a cython answer would be legitimate

@ken I also find a cython version slightly faster. The assembly it gives is 14086 lines long and I am not sure how to extract the relevant part sadly.

Clang generates a branchless assembly code which is good to avoid the overhead of branch miss-prediction. However, it add more instruction to execute. This is not so much a problem since the instruction can execute in parallel thanks to ILP and there is not enough parallelism on most recent CPU (dependent of the target CPU). Still, some additional instruction are certainly add on the critical path (eg. blend).

I did not look the Cython asm code but it is generally compiled with GCC and I my experience, GCC should generate a code with conditional branches. This is good if they are correctly predicted, but pretty bad if they are not. This is data-dependent. It should actually be dependent of the predictability of the standard deviation of the input data. I am not sure one can make a safe assumption on this probability and I think the faster performance is just circumstantial. One can get worst performance with GCC on another dataset (not to mention the branch-prediction accuracy is CPU dependent).

Moreover, the function call overhead is certainly also not the same between Numba and Cython (IDK which is better). If you really care about performance, then a well-written native code can certainly help a lot to significantly speed this up (compared to both Numba and Cython). None of the two is fast here (or can even certainly be).

@Simd I have no idea about that, as I'm not familiar with Cython. But I have some good (or bad) news for you. I tried Pythran and got 7.0e-6. Apparently, choosing the right library is extremely important in your case.

That's great news! Could you add an answer using pythran please. Does it give exactly the same output?

@ken did you compile with pythran -O3 ? I just tried it and it is faster than cython although not by that much.

I just tested Cython and Pythran on my machine. The accuracy is the same. The timings are: 1.4 µs (Numba), 1.2 µs (Cython), 1.15 µs (Pythran). Profiling results show that the above hypothesis about Cython was true : GCC (default backend compiler for Cython) generate conditional jumps and the outcome is 100% predictable by the CPU because they was always true of always false. Pythran generate a C++ code which look similar Cython. This 50 ns gap is independent of the array size. It is due to the slightly more efficient Python wrapper function.

@JeromeRichard I tried cython with clang and strangely it was a little slower than GCC for me.

@Simd It makes sense: Clang generates a branchless code which turn out to be slower than the one of GCC in practice on the target input. I checked the assembly code and found it is about the same than Numba, though my version of Clang (not matching with the one of Numba) decides to unroll the loop twice (which AFAIK does not impact much performance here).

@Simd I did not found inputs where the branch-based assembly code is very inefficient so far since abs(s) < abs(arr[i]) seems often true or predictable. np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) make branches less predictable but still not so bad.

So far, I succeed to reach 0.5 µs with a native code written in a custom low-level language and using a Numba wrapping function (because Numba is faster than ctypes for calling native functions). At this scale, the overhead of calling a native/Numba/Cython function becomes really significant. I do not think any Python-based solution can be faster than 1.0 µs on my machine.

@JeromeRichard Those speed ups would be really useful. I look forward to seeing how you did it.

TL;DR: ISPC can make this computation faster, especially if the caller Python functions are optimized with Numba or Cython (so to reduce function call overheads).

Analysis
The speed of the Numba code is limited by 3 factors:

the very long dependency chain of (1000) dependent operations * (90% of the time on my machine)
the overhead of calling a Numba function from CPython, checking parameter types and converting them into native Numba types (10% of the time on my machine)

While we can try to unroll the loop and break the dependency, the benefit will be small (if any) on most mainstream x86 CPUs because of the number of instructions to execute within the resulting loop (which is another source of bottleneck).
The key point is to use packed SIMD instructions instead of scalar ones. Technically, it means instructions like vsubsd/vaddsd/etc. (i.e. scalar ones) should be replaced by vsubpd/vaddpd/etc. (i.e. "packed" ones). However, there is apparently no simple and portable way to make Numba generate that.
The same thing is true in Cython (one can use compiler-dependent GCC vector extensions combined with some Cython tricks but some operations like blends are missing anyway...
Because floating-point math is not associative and fastmath is disabled, compilers cannot change the order of the instructions and break the dependency chain. The only solution seems to do it manually.

Faster solutions
A straightforward solution is to write a C/C++ code. One way is to use low-level x86 SIMD intrinsics. This way results in very good performance. However, it is not portable on all CPUs (e.g. only on x86 CPUs supporting AVX-2), highly bug-prone and very hard to maintain (I tried and I got a fast code which is insane to read and not accurate certainly due to a sneaky bug). Another way is to use a C++ libraries to do that, but libraries supporting operations like blends (or SIMD predication), generating efficient portable code are actually not so common (XSIMD seems a good candidate). On top of that the resulting code is often quite complex and not user-friendly for non-skilled users (code full of templates with 2 manual reductions: one needed for the remaining items and another for the SIMD items themselves).
A better solution is to use a SIMD-friendly native language like ISPC (similar to shaders/CUDA/OpenCL though ISPC supports CPUs very well compared to others). Here is an implementation:
// sum.ispc

export uniform double neumaier(uniform double arr[], uniform size_t size)
{
    double s = 0.0d;
    double c = 0.0d;

    foreach (i = 0...size)
    {
        const double item = arr[i];
        const double t = s + item;

        if(abs(s) >= abs(item))
            c += (s - t) + item;
        else
            c += (item - t) + s;

        s = t;
    }

    uniform double uni_s = 0.0d;
    uniform double uni_c = 0.0d;

    // Also applies neumaier to perform the final reduction between SIMD lanes
    foreach_active(laneId)
    {
        const uniform double item = extract(s, laneId);
        const uniform double t = uni_s + item;

        if(abs(uni_s) >= abs(item))
            uni_c += (uni_s - t) + item;
        else
            uni_c += (item - t) + uni_s;

        uni_s = t;
    }

    return uni_s + (reduce_add(c) + uni_c);
}

Note that uniform can be seen as scalar variables and varying as SIMD ones. Variables are varying by default. For more information, please read the ISPC documentation.
This implementation is actually rather simple compared to other native ones (e.g. C/C++) and it is portable since ISPC supports nearly-all mainstream x86/ARM CPUs. It is more complex than the Numba code (mainly due to the final SIMD reduction which is only meant to provide very-accurate results), but also significantly faster.
To compile it, you need the ISPC compiler and a linker. Here are the command I used to build the binaries on Linux:
# Compilation (for CPUs supporting AVX-2)
# On windows, --dllexport is maybe required
ispc sum.ispc -o sum_ispc.o --target avx2-i64x4 --pic --addressing=64

# Link: build the library
gcc --shared sum_ispc.o -o sum_ispc.so


Calling the native function from CPython
To call this function from CPython, one can use Numba, ctypes or Cython. Used alone, ctypes has a quite big overhead. It can be mixed with Numba so to reduce the overhead (thanks to the quite-fast JIT-generated wrapper-function of Numba). The fastest solution is clearly to use C extensions of CPython but this is quite painful to write (though the overhead is 2 times smaller on my machine).
Here is an example of way to use ctypes + Numba:
import numba as nb
import ctypes

ispcLib = ctypes.CDLL('./sum_ispc.so')
ispcLib.neumaier.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t]
ispcLib.neumaier.restype = ctypes.c_double
neumaier_ctypes_ispc = ispcLib.neumaier

# Faster optional Numba wrapper (than calling neumaier_ctypes_ispc directly)
@nb.njit('(float64[::1],)')
def neumaier_numba_ispc(arr):
    return neumaier_ctypes_ispc(arr.ctypes.data, arr.size)

To call the ISPC function from Cython, you can let ISPC generate a header file then included in the Cython generated code thanks to a cdef extern bloc (as mentioned by DavidW in comments). The header can be generated by adding the flag --header-outfile=sum_ispc.h to the ISPC command line. Here is an example:
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "sum_ispc.h":
    double neumaier(const double* arr, size_t size);

cpdef np.float64_t neumaier_wrapper(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
    return neumaier(&arr[0], arr.size)

If you already use Numba in the caller function, then it is certainly better to just load and declare the ISPC function with ctypes. If you already use Cython instead, then the later solution is much better. If the caller function is written in pure Python, then you can use Numba or Cython to reduce the function call overhead (Cython is more flexible for that).

Accuracy and performance results
On both np.random.rand(1000) and np.random.normal(0,1,1000), I get exactly the same output with ISPC than Numba and Cython.
Here are performance results on my machine (with a i5-9600KF CPU on Linux):
When called from a pure-Python function:
    Numba:              1.41 µs ± 0.234 ns/loop
    Cython:             1.21 µs ± 0.334 ns/loop
    Pythran:            1.16 µs ± 0.128 ns/loop

    ISPC + ctypes:      1.60 µs ± 15.9 ns/loop
    ISPC + Numba:       0.48 µs ± 0.123 ns/loop     <-----
    ISPC + Cython:      0.50 ns ± 0.743 ns/loop     <-----
    ISPC + C-ext:       0.38 µs ± 0.064 ns/loop     <-----

    Estimated optimal:  0.30 µs

When called from a Numba function:
    ISPC + Numba:       0.35 µs                     <-----

When called from a Cython function:
    ISPC + Cython:      0.34 µs                     <-----

* mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50,000 loops each

The fastest ISPC solution is about 3 times faster than Numba/Cython/Pythran when called from a pure-Python function. Otherwise, it can be up to 4 times faster.

"The fastest solution is clearly to use C extensions of CPython but this is quite painful to write" - one of the nice things about Cython is that you can put your Python/compiled-code boundary essentially wherever you want. So you write your fast ispc code, and call it from Cython (with cdef extern) and that's a direct C function call.

...so if you're finding it expensive to call the Cython wrapper from Python, you just compile a bit more of it in Cython and move the expensive call further out.

Good point for using Cython in the caller function to reduce the overhead! This trick is not possible in Numba because it cannot compile code with objects (there is a mode for that but it is inefficient/useless in practice) while Cython can (and improve performance).

I updated the answer and added the ISPC+Cython version as well as version calling ISPC directly from Cython/Numba functions.
