How to find the assembly for a cython function?
I have this cython code:
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False

cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

def neumaier_sum(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
    cdef np.float64_t s = arr[0]
    cdef np.float64_t c = 0.0
    cdef np.float64_t t
    cdef int i
    cdef int n = arr.size

    for i in range(1, n):
        t = s + arr[i]
        if abs(s) >= abs(arr[i]):
            c += (s - t) + arr[i]
        else:
            c += (arr[i] - t) + s
        s = t
    return s + c

I have tried both objdump -d and cython and then gcc -S but both give massively long assembly outputs. How can I get the assembly for just this function?

I'm not an assembly guru, so manual inspection seemed impossible, I used Godbolt - copy the generated C, add "Python" library and watch the compiler output. You can Ctrl+F10 to jump from a C function line to corresponding assembly entries.

@STerliakov  I really want to know the assembly that cython is making. The c it produces is similarly unintelligible.

Cython does not produce any assembly, it generates a C file that you feed to some compiler later (e.g. gcc), which produces assembly (with -S) or a .so library file.

@STerliakov Yes. The problem is that the C is unintelligible.

Hm, are you looking for cython -a? It will produce a .html file showing correspondence between original Cython lines and emitted C code, then it should be trivial to locate those lines in a whole C file.

@STerliakov Yes. But how do I then go from that to getting the assembly?

I just piped objdump -S to less and searched there for my_function_name>: (e.g. /neumaier_sum>: - that will move to the start of the corresponding C function. Make sure to add -g to gcc invocation beforehand to have enough debugging symbols. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If you want to look at the assembly of the function body, then find that function in C and use any convenient tool to watch C -> ASM mapping. It's not even a question about Cython - you want to see the compilation result of a C function.

@STerliakov I am trying to understand why it is slightly faster than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78633770/can-neumaier-summation-be-sped-up by inspecting the assembly.

Cython generates C code.
Once generated, scripts like setup.py or modules like pyximport will compile the C code to a object file and then link it to produce a shared object library on Linux or a dynamic library (a.k.a. DLL) on Windows. To do that, they execute the default compiler/linker on the target platform (GCC/LD on Linux and AFAIK the MSVC tool-chain on Windows).
You can compile Cython code yourself. Here is an example of Linux script:
# Require pkg-config to find the CPython-related flags
cython sum.pyx # Generate "sum.c"
gcc -O3 --shared -c sum.c $(pkg-config --cflags python3) -fPIC
gcc --shared sum.o -o sum.so $(pkg-config --libs python3)

You can easily change the command line so to write the generated assembly:
gcc -O3 --shared -S sum.c $(pkg-config --cflags python3) -fPIC

This command will generate the file sum.s (note the new -S).
Note that the assembly code of a C file is generally much bigger than the C file itself so if the C files is unintelligible then the assembly will certainly be too. On my machine, the assembly file contains more than 4000 lines... You can focus on parts containing the target function name. The main computing functions still takes >800 lines. AFAIK, there are GCC flags to map the assembly code with the C code but it is generally pretty-difficult to navigate in such big assembly/C code.
A better solution is to profile the code using a low-level profiler (e.g. VTune or Linux perf). You can then quite-easily find the assembly code of hot loops in this big assembly code.

Example
Here is the assembly code of the hot loop I got with a low-level profiler (using pyximport with default arguments calling GCC with -O2):
        jmp        1d0
 1b8:┌─→subsd      xmm1,xmm0            \
     │  add        rdx,0x1               |
     │  add        rcx,rbp               |
     │  addsd      xmm1,xmm2             | Part of the main loop 
     │  addsd      xmm3,xmm1             | never executed
     │  cmp        rbx,rdx               |
     │↓ je         20a                  /
     │
 1d0:│  movsd      xmm1,QWORD PTR [rcx] \   <--- loop entry-point
     │  movapd     xmm2,xmm0             |
     │  movapd     xmm6,xmm2             |
     │  movapd     xmm5,xmm1             |
     │  andpd      xmm6,xmm4             |
     │  addsd      xmm0,xmm1             |
     │  andpd      xmm5,xmm4             |
     │  comisd     xmm6,xmm5             | Part of the main loop 
     └──jb         1b8                   | always executed
        subsd      xmm2,xmm0             |
        add        rdx,0x1               |
        add        rcx,rbp               |
        addsd      xmm2,xmm1             |
        addsd      xmm3,xmm2             |
        cmp        rbx,rdx               |
      ↑ jne        1d0                  /


The assembly looks very different to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78633770/1473517 to me as a non expert. How does the comparison look to you?

I already commented this in comments below your linked post ;) . Put it shortly, the main difference is that this code performs (more) conditional branches while the other is (mainly) branchless.
